# rotate shape become rotate and translating

Tags: c, opengl

I'm new on using openGL, and now I'm trying to rotate the square i made, but when I rotate it, the square doesn't only rotate, but also moving around while rotating. I think I made a mistake on the rotate and translate process, but cannot find the the solution

```
void drawSquare(double x,double y, int num)
{
  double xLength = 0.6;
  double yLength = 0.6;

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
       glLoadIdentity();
       glPushMatrix();      
       glTranslatef(0, 0, 0.0f);
       glRotatef(angleCW, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f);

       glBegin( GL_QUADS );

       if(i%2==0)
       {
         glColor3f(gCurrentRed,gCurrentGreen,gCurrentBlue);

       }
       else
       {
         glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
       }
       glVertex3f(x,y,0);
       glVertex3f(x+xLength,y,0);
       glVertex3f(x+xLength,y+yLength,0);
       glVertex3f(x,y+yLength,0);
       xLength -=0.1;
       yLength -=0.1;
       x += 0.05;
       y += 0.05;
       glEnd();
       glPopMatrix();
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to rotate first and then translate, since when you rotate something it always rotate around `(0, 0, 0)`

Comment: i've tried to rotate it first, but it gives the same result

Comment: @ThanushanBalakrishnan: OpenGL is not a scene graph. glTranslate and glRotate merely change the values of the matrices that the vertices are multiplied with when drawing. Once a primitive has been drawn any changes to the matrices have no further effect.

Comment: @ThanushanBalakrishnan: Please don't give advise if you're (admittedly) don't know how the subject at question actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quads are going to rotate around the origin (0,0,0). If that's not in the middle of your quads then it is going to *look* like it is translating too. Maybe you can translate it so the quads a centered, rotate it, and then translate it back

**Edit:**

See @datenwolf's comment for an example where he:

1. creates the quad with 0,0,0 as the center
2. rotates the quad
3. translates the quad to its position

Comment: could you give the example in code? because i don't really understand

Comment: @user2629285 `glTranslatef(+(x+xLength)/2, +(y+yLength/2), 0); glRotatef(…); glTranslatef(-(x+xLength)/2, -(y+yLength/2), 0);`. BTW: a `glTranslatef(0,0,0);` has no effect at all; it's an identity transform.