# Translating according to the distance

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a square at the origin. First, I want to rotate it.Then, translate it 5 units away from the origin.

After rotation I want to translate it for a distance of 5. But when I implement the code below. It does not translate it to where I want. What is the correct way to Translate.
`glTranslatef( 5,5, 5); glRotatef(45, x,y,z);`

Comment: Which are you doing first? You say you want to rotate and then translate, but the code you posted is in the other order. Either way, try reversing the order of the operations.

Comment: Dont you do the operation closest to what you are drawing first? Because I create my square after glRotatef

Comment: Rotate and then translate for one thing. Generally if you want to rotate an object, you want to rotate the object around its center (this is object-space < 0, 0, 0 >, but if you translate first you throw that out the window).

Comment: is your square centered at the origin? if so then call translatef first then call the rotation.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman doesnt opengl use a stack, so the last operation added is called first (so the rotate needs to be written last to be called first)?

Comment: No, it multiplies matrix functions like `glTranslatef (...)` and `glRotatef (...)` against the **current** matrix immediately. It does have a matrix stack, but that is used for different purposes.

Comment: When I want to translate the square by 5 away from the origin.Do I do `glTranslatef(5,5,5)`or `glTranslatef(5,0,0)` Assuming 5 away using x axis or all 3 axis'?

Comment: `glTranslatef (5, 5, 5)` actually translates [`8.66 units`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+%28%280%2C0%2C0%29%20%2C%285%2C5%2C5%29%29) -- sqrt (5^2 + 5^2 + 5^2). `glTranslatef (5, 0, 0)` on the other hand translates 5 units in the X direction.

Comment: If you want to move 5 units in the +X, +Y, +Z direction then I would recommend you normalize (1, 1, 1) and multiply it by 5. Or: (5/sqrt(3), 5/sqrt(3), 5/sqrt(3)) ~= (2.887, 2.887, 2.887)

Comment: Can you post your code? May be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974277/rotate-shape-become-rotate-and-translating?noredirect=1#comment28037492_18974277

Comment: `glRotatef(angle,X,Y,Z);
 glTranslatef(distance, Distance,Z);

 glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
 glColor3f(10.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(-25.0, -25.0, 0);
       glVertex3f(25.0, -25.0, 0);
       glVertex3f(25.0, 25.0, 0);
       glVertex3f(-25.0, 25.0, 0);
    glEnd(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your square center is at the origin, glTranslatef then glRotatef.

To rotate about a custom center, here is the generic formula :

```
TranslationFromRotCenterToOrigin * RotationMatrix * TranslationFromOriginToRotCenter
```

which gives something in reverse order in OpenGL ( cause glTranslatef/glRotatef multiplies the current OpenGL matrix by the specified translation/rotation matrix )

```
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef( 5, 5, 5);
glTranslatef( toRotCenterX, toRotCenterY, toRotCenterZ );
glRotatef( 45, x, y, z );
glTranslatef( -toRotCenterX, -toRotCenterY, -toRotCenterZ );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Mine is at the origin, so I do but I dont get the right answer
`glTranslatef(Distance/sqrt(3), Distance/sqrt(3),Distance/sqrt(3)); glRotatef(angle,X,Y,Z); `

Comment: Is your square **center** at the origin or your square **corner**

Comment: Maybe we don't understand your problem. Can you post a snapshot of what you get and what you expect? Feel free to add any information on the snapshot like the translation and rotation you expect, where is the origin and what is your current viewport

Comment: The origin of the square is at (0,0). I want to translate the origin 5 away from the origin after I do my Rotation. Rotation works fine. I am guessing since I do not have a Z axis my plane normal is (0,0,1). so from using the equation d=NP i get d= (0,0,1)(x,y,z). From that equation i get d=z. So I thought i could just translate the z axis but when I do that.

Comment: If your model view is identity and you translate along Z in orthogonal projection you won't get any result.

Comment: It's ismodrlview. So what should I do?

Comment: I don't understand : 

> "So I thought i could just translate the z axis but when I do that"

and 

> "It's ismodrlview. So what should I do?"

Again, you should post a snapshot of what you want and what you get. It'll help us understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I couldnt figure out how to post the picture so I took a pic and put it in to this link. In the picture you can see that when I translate it. It does not end up where my object is.Rotation is correct.[https://www.dropbox.com/s/7iu1u6ykhuhssbk/1234.jpg]

Comment: Maybe it's your other object that is not where you expect. Double check the coordinates of your other object. It's probably something simple, try to mess with the values to know what's the problem. After some debugging you should get what you expect.